# How to check for proper format in my API response

Tags: rest, flask, python-requests, python-unittest

Currently running tests for my REST API which:

1. takes an endpoint from the user
2. using that endpoint, grabs info from a server
3. sends it to another server to be translated
4. then proceeds to `jsonify` the data.

I've written a series of automated tests running and I cannot get one to pass - the test that actually identifies the content of the response. I've tried including several variations of what the test is expecting but I feel it's the actual implementation that's the issue. Here's the expected API response from the client request:

```
{ "name": "random_character", "description": "Translated description of requested character is output here" }
```

**Here is the testing class inside my test_main.py:**

```
class Test_functions(unittest.TestCase):

    # checking if response of 200 is returned
    def test_healthcheck_PokeAPI(self):
        manualtest = app.test_client(self)
        response = manualtest.get("/pokemon/")
        status_code = response.status_code
        self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)
    
    # the status code should be a redirect i.e. 308; so I made a separate test for this
    def test_healthcheck_ShakesprAPI(self):
        manualtest = app.test_client(self)
        response = manualtest.get("/pokemon/charizard")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 308)
    
    def test_response_content(self):
        manualtest = app.test_client(self)
        response = manualtest.get("/pokemon/charizard")
        self.assertEqual(response.content_type,
                         'application/json')   <<<< this test is failing
    
    def test_trans_shakespeare_response(self):
        manualtest = app.test_client(self)
        response = manualtest.get("/pokemon/charizard")
        self.assertFalse(b"doth" in response.data)
```

**Traceback:**

```
AssertionError: 'text/html; charset=utf-8' != 'application/json' - text/html; charset=utf-8 + application/json
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hm, in the previous test you check that the same request is redirected - could that be the problem? E.g. the response you expect will be received from the request after the redirect, while here you get just the redirect message?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly: It's a different response, actually. 2 different endpoints. First request gives me 200, the second gives me 308 before giving me 200 as it's a redirect, as you said.

Comment: Yes - have you checked the content of the response? I is text, so you easily verify if this is the problem.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, how might I go about doing that? I don't think I'm understanding "I is text"

Comment: Sorry, typo... I mean the response contains HTML Text which you can check in your test - my guess is that it is a redirect message, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I've tried that already, actually. I used `self.assertEqual(response.content_type, 'text/html; application/json')` instead of what I already have in my posted code. Test still failed, though

Comment: Yes, but what does the response actually contain? The actual content that you get just by using `print` or a debugger.